# (401 error) After installing dj-rest-auth and deleted a user from user table, server keeps returning 401 error for all endpoints

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-401, dj-rest-auth

I'm trying to use login/connect social accounts using **dj-rest-auth**. I use postman to test api request.
I installed according to [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doc.
I worked smoothly until I delete a user from user table.

My testing process steps:

1. dj-rest-auth/login [**user 1** credential] -> get correct result [user 1]
2. delete [user 1] in DB
3. dj-rest-auth/login [user 1 credential] -> user not found [401 unauthorize]
4. dj-rest-auth/login [**user 2** credential] -> user not found [401 unauthorize] ( **user 2 exist in table**)
5. all other api get 401 error (user not found [401 unauthorize])

Do I need to add some setting for this case?
I have no idea How deleted user affected to all other api

Please advise me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved after I removed (JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'auth').

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add those settings in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken', # this
    'dj_rest_auth', # this
    'myapp',
]


REST_USE_JWT = True # this (apply JWT auth)
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'jwt-auth' # this
```

Check also this settings in project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("myapp.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')), # this

]
```

if still get an error add this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    )
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added all those code lines, and it still causes the problem. It is solved after I removed (JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'auth').
I don't know why that cause error though